# How to disable Android assert (with Eclipse on Windows)

Tags: android, junit, assert

How can I disable assert checks on Windows through Eclipse?

I have tried using

```
-assumenosideeffects junit.framework.Assert {
*;
}
```

but the aseert check still runs.

I have seen `adb shell setprop debug.assert 1` as another solution, but I am using Eclipse.

Comment: The adb shell is not necessarily incompatible with Eclipse-based development, assuming you have eclipse re-launching into the same emulator and not starting a new one every time.

Answer (score 2):

About the adb shell setprop debug.assert 1 you can do in any system because with adb shell you set the property in Android OS not in your computer OS. But in any case it is for java language assert not for JUnit assert you mention.

If you try to remove the JUnit assert use:

> -assumenosideeffects **class** junit.framework.Assert {   *; }

and it has to work. But note that it will only apply when you Export a package not in a normal run.